# How integrate @JsonView of jackson with grails and jax-rs?

Tags: grails, groovy, jersey, jackson

I have a grails project which uses jax-rs plugin with jersey and I would like use @JsonView described by http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews.

Actually, resources works but jsonview is not interpreted.

How I can do that ?